# How can i user second firebase project in my flutter app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, twitter-oauth

I am working in project which has already built and has a firebase project but now I want to add social authentication of Twitter into this app for which I have to create another firebase project because i don't have the access to first firebase project but I don't know how to connect second firebase project in the same app. How to connect firebase project to the same app. And my second question is: Can we do Twitter authentication without using firebase? if yes then how?

Comment: You should be able to add the Twitter authentication to an existing project: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login (steps are likely similar if you are working on a native app)

Comment: I am not using js i am using dart flutter .

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social#twitter for the second part, but please limit yourself to a single topic per post.

Answer (score 2):

While not yet documented specifically for Flutter, the process is very similar for all supported platforms and documented in [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application). The crux is that you create a separate `FirebaseApp` instance for each project, and then access the services for the correct project through the corresponding instance.

For Flutter, the code would look something like this:

```
var app1 = await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: '...',
    appId: '...',
    ...
  )
);
var app2 = await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: '...',
    appId: '...',
    ...
  )
);
```